# Pandas Concat vs append and join columns --> ("state", "state:", "State")

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I join 437 tables and I get 3 columns for state as my coworkers feel like giving it a different name each day, ("state", "state:" and "State"), is there a way that joins those 3 columns to just 1 column called "state"?.

`*also my code uses append, I just saw its deprecated, will it work the same using concat? any way to make it give the same results as append?.`

I tried:

```
excl_merged.rename(columns={"state:": "state", "State": "state"})
```

but it doesn't do anything.

The code I use:

```
# importing the required modules
import glob
import pandas as pd
 
# specifying the path to csv files
path = "X:/.../Admission_merge"
 
# csv files in the path
file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
 
# list of excel files we want to merge.
# pd.read_excel(file_path) reads the excel
# data into pandas dataframe.
excl_list = []
 
for file in file_list:
    excl_list.append(pd.read_excel(file)) #use .concat will it give the columns in the same order? 
 
# create a new dataframe to store the
# merged excel file.
excl_merged = pd.DataFrame()
 
for excl_file in excl_list:
     
    # appends the data into the excl_merged
    # dataframe.
    excl_merged = excl_merged.append(
      excl_file, ignore_index=True)


# exports the dataframe into excel file with
# specified name.
excl_merged.to_excel('X:/.../***/total_admission_2021-2023.xlsx', index=False)
print("Merge finished")
```

Any suggestions how I can improve it? also is there a way to remove unnamed empty columns?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `pd.concat` instead of `append`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat`:

```
excl_list = ['state1.xlsx', 'state2.xlsx', 'state3.xlsx']
state_map = {'state:': 'state', 'State': 'state'}

data = []
for excl_file in excl_list:
    df = pd.read_excel(excl_file)

    # Case where first row is empty
    if df.columns[0].startswith('Unnamed'):
        df.columns = df.iloc[0]
        df = df.iloc[1:]

    df = df.rename(columns=state_map)
    data.append(df)
excl_merged = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)


# Output
  ID state
0  A     a
1  B     b
2  C     c
3  D     d
4  E     e
5  F     f
6  G     g
7  H     h
8  I     i
```

file1.xlsx:

```
  ID State
0  A     a
1  B     b
2  C     c
```

file2.xlsx:

```
  ID state
0  D     d
1  E     e
2  F     f
```

file3.xlsx:

```
  ID state:
0  G      g
1  H      h
2  I      i
```

If you have empty columns, you can use `data.append(df.dropna(how='all', axis=1))` before appending to data list.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, by the way, is there a way to detect and erase when they start the table headers at line 2 instead of line 1? 12 files of the 400 apparently had the first line blank so it didn't read the column names.

Comment: When you read a correct formatted file, what is the output of `df.columns[0]` and same thing for a file with empty row?

Comment: A correctly formated column starts with *`[sample dat1 dat2 date id name ln ln2 birth phone gender origin dat3 dat4 dat5 dat6 dat7 dat8 dat9 dat10 dat11 system state errors]`*

Comment: `df.columns[0]` gives `'Unnamed: 0'` in the case of having a file a row blank (starting on the second row the table).